# Loading profile pictures with Graph API not working for large user IDs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, image, userid

I'm trying to load in the profile pictures of a large array of users, but I was finding that a few weren't loading in. When I tracked these down, it seems that they have much higher user IDs than the others, above 100000000000000.

I've tried this on the Graph API Explorer too and this also gets stuck loading the 'picture' connection with users with these high IDs. Other connections for these users load OK, and I can see the pictures when I visit the URL in the browser.

Is there any reason that the API would have a problem loading these?

Answer (score 0):

The graph.facebook.com/me/picture is not json, the GraphAPI Explorer doesn't even show these. Its an actual picture, open it up as a url in your browser.

Comment: Figured out the problems, the larger IDs were too big for the 'int' type in Flash.

Completely barking up the wrong tree. Thanks for the help though.